# How can I change url parameter value using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to validate url parameters using htaccess, where a certain parameter needs to have a valid value. If the value for the parameter is invalid, I want to redirect to another page.

E.g.: www.mydomain.com/folder/page1?specialId=1a3b5c78

The value for the "specialId" parameter needs to be an 8 character string.
If the value is invalid (e.g.: 1a3b5c78x or abc) I want to redirect to  www.mydomain.com/folder/page2

Answer (score 0):

You can use in your `htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} specialId [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !specialId=[A-Z]{8}(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule page1/?$ /folder/page2? [R=301,NC,L]
```